# Disable action if textarea is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could I somehow disable action (send, redirect) from submit if the textarea was empty (so nothing at all happens onclick).  I want to avoid displaying error here, thats why I'm asking.

My textarea:

```
<textarea id="message" name="message" maxlength="35"></textarea>
```

My submit button:

```
<input id="send" type="image" src="/site_media/static/images/submit.png" value="Submit">
```

This is what i tried: http://jsfiddle.net/5Xwyb/

My brain died couple of hours ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will stop all attempts to submit if #message is empty.

```
$(function(){
   $("#send").submit(function(event){

       if($("#message").val().length === 0))
          event.preventDefault();

       // other submit code

    });
});​
```

Comment: If we're being technically correct (and we are:)): .length === 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){

   $("#send").submit(function(e){

      if($("#message").val()==""))
      {      
        e.preventDefault();
       }
    });        

});​
```

JsFiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/5Xwyb/7/

Comment: Don't use <code>return false;</code>. use <code>$("form").submit(function( e ){</code> with <code>e.preventDefault();</code> instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false for info. Updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iknowkungfoo/5Xwyb/6/